# Is it possible to extend or deactive AAD B2C invite Link

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an app that uses AAD B2C user management. Users can send invite links via email. The invite link has an expiry of 7 days according to the JWT config. We store the invitation as application data in a user management database.

Our problem is that some users do not except the invite within 7 days. For the moment we see two possibilities.

1. extend the invite Link to 30 days (which is not allowed)
2. Disable the expiration

Any other ideas? or at least an idea how to disable the exipration?

my GenerateInviteToken.xml looks like

```
  <ClaimsProviders>
<!-- variant of default JwtIssuer to lower the token lifetime for the invite we send -->
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuerInvite">
      <DisplayName>JWT Issuer Invite</DisplayName>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">604800</Item>  
        <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">900</Item>
        <Item Key="refresh_token_lifetime_secs">604800</Item>
        <Item Key="rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs">604.801</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims/>
      <OutputClaims/>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: You could also regenerate a new link

Comment: how do I regenerate a new link?

Comment: you said `Users can send invite links via email` => can't they not resend a new link?

Comment: If the invite is send using id_token_hint, then there might be an initial token validation is happening (like token expiry). Change that logic that may fix your problem.

Comment: sry that is wrong stated. an external application sends the invite and not the users